# Drop down menu parent link to itself

Tags: drupal-7

am using the bootstrap theme with nice menu module and menu token module. I have a dropdown menu that look like =>

```
-about
  -What are we?
```

So the parent should link to # as it has no link. So the path I entered [current-page:url]/#. But it shows baseurl/?q=node/# instead of #. How to shows # only?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Menu Firstchild](https://drupal.org/project/menu_firstchild) module, which lets you enter `<firstchild>` in the path field. The "about" link will then point to the first sub-item of your menu. Or you can install the [Special menu items](https://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) module, which has a `<nolink>` feature that provides a menu entry not linked to any page.